# Is it possible to access data from another artifact in Azure Blueprints ONLY using Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-blueprints

I've been trying to access data from one artifact (ARM-template) in another artifact (ARM-template) that is on the same level. Apparently, passing data between artifacts is possible using output and reference function, as shown in this [guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-blueprints/tree/15fa73b6b71bb9c093978b3a6a0f481a8a4aaa1d#passing-values-between-artifacts). However, the guide only shows how to do this in code, namely Azure PowerShell, and I haven't found any solutions to do this in the portal. So, is this possible?

This image shows two artifacts in a resource group. I want to pass the name of the service bus being created when this blueprint is assigned to the eventGridTopic. As you can see, the artifacts are on the same level.

[image: screenshot of the same]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. E.g. I need to use the log analytics workspace name in the following AKS cluster deployment.

So first put that name in the outputs of the laworkspace artifact.
[laworkspace artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjbLl.png)

Then reference to it in the aks-cluster artifact when giving the value to the corresponding parameter like below.  You may also reference to it in the resource definition directly in the ARM template.

[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/', artifacts('laworkspace').outputs.laWorkspaceName)]

[aks-cluster artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXlla.png)

I normally export a blueprint to source code, modify the code in my favorite editor, and then import it back to Azure.